# #2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2003

I just installed wamp.. I have mysql 5.1.33... On the icon in the task bar it says that the server is online, but when I go to open PHPMyAdmin, it gives me error 2003. Please help

Comment: This might help: http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html

Answer (score 0):

This problem might have occured due to database connectivity problem(not connected to MySQL database or MySQL service not started).
For me I did the following tasks to solve the issue.

```
Go to:- C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.51b\bin\mysqld-nt.exe

and then in the wapserver menu "Restart All Services".
```

This worked for me.Hope this solution works for others too.